# BISON and YACC - How to input a complete statement

Tags: bison, yacc, lex

This is my first time trying out BISON and I'm stuck trying to figure out how to take a complete statement for example `astros = 2`. Whenever I try to do that, I don't get any output. But if I try each part separately then I get output for each part. My code is as follow, just part of it of course:

.y file

```
%token ASSIGNMENT
%token <intToken> INTNUMBER
%token <intToken> INTTOKEN
%type <statement> STATEMENT

STATEMENT:    '\n'
              | INTTOKEN STATEMENT {printf("Token");}
              | INTNUMBER STATEMENT {printf("Number");}
              | STATEMENT ASSIGNMENT STATEMENT{printf("Assinging");}
              |  INTTOKEN '\t' ASSIGNMENT '\t' INTNUMBER STATEMENT {printf("FULL STATEMENT COMPLETE");}

               |error {yyerror("ERROR");}
```

My .l file:

```
"="                                 return ASSIGNMENT;
[0-9]+                      { ECHO; yylval.integer = atoi(yytext); return INTNUMBER; }
[a-fA-F]+[a-zA-Z]+      { ECHO; yylval.variableInteger = yytext; return INTTOKEN; }
```

Also if someone could explain me how the rules of the tokens work then that would be great. Maybe like that I can figure it by myself.

Comment: Perhaps you should take a look at the [flex manual](http://flex.sourceforge.net/manual/Simple-Examples.html#Simple-Examples), or John Levine's book on Bison and Flex (O'Reilly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rules are simple, Lex is searching sequentially for regular expressions, matching tokens and giving them to Yacc. Yacc is using `yylex()` function for this purpose.

Your question is not complete. Do you have something else written in Yacc file?

Yacc file consists of three parts:

- C code that is later located somewhere near start of y.tab.c file (that Yacc generates), in this part of the file you need to declare `extern int yylex(void)` function. Yacc actually needs two things to work, first one is `yylex()` and seccond is `yyerror()`.
- Second part is Grammar with rules and actions
- Third part is main function where you call yyparse().

As for declaration of tokens and types, that can be done before or after `%{ %}` part of the file. Some basic Yacc code would look like this:

```
%{ 
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include ...

 /* Extern keyword is just good practice, it doesn't have to be written */
 extern int yylex(void);

 void yyerror(char *string){

   fprintf(stderr,"Syntax error: %s", string);
   exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
 }

%}

%%
  /* Grammar with actions */
%%

int main(){

  yyparse();
  return 0;
}
```

So how does this work? Yacc is using `yylex()` function to get tokens and then his grammar to determine everything else. In order this to work, you have to compile both `lex.yy.c` generated with flex and `y.tab.c` generated with yacc to object file, and then compile those two object files into one executable.

For example:

```
yacc program.y
flex program.lex
gcc -c y.tab.c -o y.tab.o
gcc -c lex.yy.c -o lex.yy.o
gcc y.tab.o lex.yy.o -o program
```

**Note:** If you're declaring tokens in `Yacc` file, you need to generate  `y.tab.h` file when running Yacc command with `yacc -d program.y` and then to include this file in your Lex. Option -d is for that.